# How can I stop Rtabmap from publishing transform data on /tf topic?

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rtabmap-odometry, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to implement slam on a mobile robot. I have created my own frames and linked them and I am publishing them on /tf
I do not want rtabmap to publish its own transforms on this topic (I am using rtabmap only for visual odometry)
I have a launch file as follows:

```
<launch>
  <!-- Convenience launch file to launch odometry, rtabmap and rtabmapviz nodes at once -->

  <!-- For stereo:=false
        Your RGB-D sensor should be already started with "depth_registration:=true".
        Examples:
           $ roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch depth_registration:=true 
           $ roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch depth_registration:=true -->
           
  <!-- For stereo:=true
        Your camera should be calibrated and publishing rectified left and right 
        images + corresponding camera_info msgs. You can use stereo_image_proc for image rectification.
        Example:
           $ roslaunch rtabmap_ros bumblebee.launch -->
     
  <!-- Choose between RGB-D and stereo -->      
  <arg name="stereo"          default="false"/>
 
  <!-- Choose visualization -->
  <arg name="rtabmapviz"              default="false" /> 
  <arg name="rviz"                    default="false" />
  
  <!-- Localization-only mode -->
  <arg name="localization"            default="false"/>
  
  <!-- Corresponding config files -->
  <arg name="cfg"                     default="" /> <!-- To change RTAB-Map's parameters, set the path of config file (*.ini) generated by the standalone app -->
  <arg name="gui_cfg"                 default="~/.ros/rtabmap_gui.ini" />
  <arg name="rviz_cfg"                default="$(find rtabmap_ros)/launch/config/rgbd.rviz" />
  
  <arg name="frame_id"                default="camera_link"/>     <!-- Fixed frame id, you may set "base_link" or "base_footprint" if they are published -->
  <arg name="namespace"               default="rtabmap"/>
  <arg name="database_path"           default="~/.ros/rtabmap.db"/>
  <arg name="queue_size"              default="10"/>
  <arg name="wait_for_transform"      default="0.2"/>
  <arg name="rtabmap_args"            default=""/>              <!-- delete_db_on_start, udebug -->
  <arg name="launch_prefix"           default=""/>              <!-- for debugging purpose, it fills launch-prefix tag of the nodes -->
  
  <!-- if timestamps of the input topics are synchronized using approximate or exact time policy-->
  <arg     if="$(arg stereo)" name="approx_sync"  default="false"/>
  <arg unless="$(arg stereo)" name="approx_sync"  default="true"/>         
   
  <!-- RGB-D related topics -->
  <arg name="rgb_topic"               default="/camera/rgb/image_rect_color" />
  <arg name="depth_topic"             default="/camera/depth_registered/image_raw" />
  <arg name="camera_info_topic"       default="/camera/rgb/camera_info" />
  
  <!-- stereo related topics -->
  <arg name="stereo_namespace"        default="/stereo_camera"/>
  <arg name="left_image_topic"        default="$(arg stereo_namespace)/left/image_rect_color" />
  <arg name="right_image_topic"       default="$(arg stereo_namespace)/right/image_rect" />      <!-- using grayscale image for efficiency -->
  <arg name="left_camera_info_topic"  default="$(arg stereo_namespace)/left/camera_info" />
  <arg name="right_camera_info_topic" default="$(arg stereo_namespace)/right/camera_info" />
  
  <arg name="compressed"              default="false"/>         <!-- If you want to subscribe to compressed image topics -->
  <arg name="rgb_image_transport"     default="compressed"/>    <!-- Common types: compressed, theora (see "rosrun image_transport list_transports") -->
  <arg name="depth_image_transport"   default="compressedDepth"/>  <!-- Common types: compressed, theora (see "rosrun image_transport list_transports") -->
   
  <arg name="subscribe_scan"          default="false"/>
  <arg name="scan_topic"              default="/scan"/>
  
  <arg name="subscribe_scan_cloud"    default="false"/>
  <arg name="scan_cloud_topic"        default="/scan_cloud"/>
   
  <arg name="visual_odometry"         default="true"/>          <!-- Launch rtabmap visual odometry node -->
  <arg name="odom_topic"              default="/odom"/>         <!-- Odometry topic used if visual_odometry is false -->
  <arg name="odom_frame_id"           default=""/>              <!-- If set, TF is used to get odometry instead of the topic -->
  <arg name="odom_args"               default="$(arg rtabmap_args)"/>
  
  <!-- These arguments should not be modified directly, see referred topics without "_relay" suffix above -->
  <arg if="$(arg compressed)"     name="rgb_topic_relay"           default="$(arg rgb_topic)_relay"/>
  <arg unless="$(arg compressed)" name="rgb_topic_relay"           default="$(arg rgb_topic)"/>
  <arg if="$(arg compressed)"     name="depth_topic_relay"         default="$(arg depth_topic)_relay"/>
  <arg unless="$(arg compressed)" name="depth_topic_relay"         default="$(arg depth_topic)"/>
  <arg if="$(arg compressed)"     name="left_image_topic_relay"    default="$(arg left_image_topic)_relay"/>
  <arg unless="$(arg compressed)" name="left_image_topic_relay"    default="$(arg left_image_topic)"/>
  <arg if="$(arg compressed)"     name="right_image_topic_relay"   default="$(arg right_image_topic)_relay"/>
  <arg unless="$(arg compressed)" name="right_image_topic_relay"   default="$(arg right_image_topic)"/>

  <!-- Nodes -->
  <group ns="$(arg namespace)">
  
    <!-- RGB-D Odometry -->
    <group unless="$(arg stereo)">
      <node if="$(arg compressed)" name="republish_rgb" type="republish" pkg="image_transport" args="$(arg rgb_image_transport) in:=$(arg rgb_topic) raw out:=$(arg rgb_topic_relay)" />
      <node if="$(arg compressed)" name="republish_depth" type="republish" pkg="image_transport" args="$(arg depth_image_transport) in:=$(arg depth_topic) raw out:=$(arg depth_topic_relay)" />
  
      <node if="$(arg visual_odometry)" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rgbd_odometry" name="rgbd_odometry" output="screen" args="$(arg odom_args)" launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)">
        <remap from="rgb/image"       to="$(arg rgb_topic_relay)"/>
        <remap from="depth/image"     to="$(arg depth_topic_relay)"/>
        <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="$(arg camera_info_topic)"/>
      
        <param name="frame_id"                    type="string" value="$(arg frame_id)"/>
        <param name="wait_for_transform_duration" type="double" value="$(arg wait_for_transform)"/>
        <param name="approx_sync"                 type="bool"   value="$(arg approx_sync)"/>
        <param name="config_path"                 type="string" value="$(arg cfg)"/>
        <param name="queue_size"                  type="int" value="$(arg queue_size)"/>
      </node>
    </group>
    
    <!-- Stereo Odometry -->
    <group if="$(arg stereo)">
      <node if="$(arg compressed)" name="republish_left"  type="republish" pkg="image_transport" args="compressed in:=$(arg left_image_topic) raw out:=$(arg left_image_topic_relay)" />
      <node if="$(arg compressed)" name="republish_right" type="republish" pkg="image_transport" args="compressed in:=$(arg right_image_topic) raw out:=$(arg right_image_topic_relay)" />
  
      <node if="$(arg visual_odometry)" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="stereo_odometry" name="stereo_odometry" output="screen" args="$(arg odom_args)" launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)">
        <remap from="left/image_rect"        to="$(arg left_image_topic_relay)"/>
        <remap from="right/image_rect"       to="$(arg right_image_topic_relay)"/>
        <remap from="left/camera_info"       to="$(arg left_camera_info_topic)"/>
        <remap from="right/camera_info"      to="$(arg right_camera_info_topic)"/>
      
        <param name="frame_id"                    type="string" value="$(arg frame_id)"/>
        <param name="wait_for_transform_duration" type="double" value="$(arg wait_for_transform)"/>
        <param name="approx_sync"                 type="bool"   value="$(arg approx_sync)"/>
        <param name="config_path"                 type="string" value="$(arg cfg)"/>
        <param name="queue_size"                  type="int" value="$(arg queue_size)"/>
      </node>
    </group>
  
    <!-- Visual SLAM (robot side) -->
    <!-- args: "delete_db_on_start" and "udebug" -->
    <node name="rtabmap" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" output="screen" args="$(arg rtabmap_args)" launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)">
      <param     if="$(arg stereo)" name="subscribe_depth"  type="bool" value="false"/>
      <param unless="$(arg stereo)" name="subscribe_depth"  type="bool" value="true"/>
      <param name="subscribe_stereo"     type="bool"   value="$(arg stereo)"/>
      <param name="subscribe_scan"       type="bool"   value="$(arg subscribe_scan)"/>
      <param name="subscribe_scan_cloud" type="bool"   value="$(arg subscribe_scan_cloud)"/>
      <param name="frame_id"             type="string" value="$(arg frame_id)"/>
      <param name="odom_frame_id"        type="string" value="$(arg odom_frame_id)"/>
      <param name="wait_for_transform_duration"  type="double"   value="$(arg wait_for_transform)"/>
      <param name="database_path"        type="string" value="$(arg database_path)"/>
      <param name="approx_sync"          type="bool"   value="$(arg approx_sync)"/>
      <param name="config_path"          type="string" value="$(arg cfg)"/>
      <param name="queue_size"           type="int" value="$(arg queue_size)"/>
      
      <remap from="rgb/image"       to="$(arg rgb_topic_relay)"/>
      <remap from="depth/image"     to="$(arg depth_topic_relay)"/>
      <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="$(arg camera_info_topic)"/>
    
      <remap from="left/image_rect"        to="$(arg left_image_topic_relay)"/>
      <remap from="right/image_rect"       to="$(arg right_image_topic_relay)"/>
      <remap from="left/camera_info"       to="$(arg left_camera_info_topic)"/>
      <remap from="right/camera_info"      to="$(arg right_camera_info_topic)"/>
      
      <remap from="scan"                   to="$(arg scan_topic)"/>
      <remap from="scan_cloud"             to="$(arg scan_cloud_topic)"/>
      <remap unless="$(arg visual_odometry)" from="odom"  to="$(arg odom_topic)"/>
      
      <!-- localization mode -->
      <param     if="$(arg localization)" name="Mem/IncrementalMemory" type="string" value="false"/>
      <param unless="$(arg localization)" name="Mem/IncrementalMemory" type="string" value="true"/>
      <param name="Mem/InitWMWithAllNodes" type="string" value="$(arg localization)"/>
    </node>
  
    <!-- Visualisation RTAB-Map -->
    <node if="$(arg rtabmapviz)" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmapviz" name="rtabmapviz" args="-d $(arg gui_cfg)" output="screen" launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)">
      <param     if="$(arg stereo)" name="subscribe_depth"  type="bool" value="false"/>
      <param unless="$(arg stereo)" name="subscribe_depth"  type="bool" value="true"/>
      <param name="subscribe_stereo"     type="bool"   value="$(arg stereo)"/>
      <param name="subscribe_scan"       type="bool"   value="$(arg subscribe_scan)"/>
      <param name="subscribe_scan_cloud" type="bool"   value="$(arg subscribe_scan_cloud)"/>
      <param name="subscribe_odom_info"  type="bool"   value="$(arg visual_odometry)"/>
      <param name="frame_id"             type="string" value="$(arg frame_id)"/>
      <param name="odom_frame_id"        type="string" value="$(arg odom_frame_id)"/>
      <param name="wait_for_transform_duration" type="double"   value="$(arg wait_for_transform)"/>
      <param name="queue_size"           type="int" value="$(arg queue_size)"/>
      <param name="approx_sync"                 type="bool"   value="$(arg approx_sync)"/>
    
      <remap from="rgb/image"       to="$(arg rgb_topic_relay)"/>
      <remap from="depth/image"     to="$(arg depth_topic_relay)"/>
      <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="$(arg camera_info_topic)"/>
      
      <remap from="left/image_rect"        to="$(arg left_image_topic_relay)"/>
      <remap from="right/image_rect"       to="$(arg right_image_topic_relay)"/>
      <remap from="left/camera_info"       to="$(arg left_camera_info_topic)"/>
      <remap from="right/camera_info"      to="$(arg right_camera_info_topic)"/>
      
      <remap from="scan"                   to="$(arg scan_topic)"/>
      <remap from="scan_cloud"             to="$(arg scan_cloud_topic)"/>
      <remap unless="$(arg visual_odometry)" from="odom"  to="$(arg odom_topic)"/>
    </node>
  
  </group>
  
  <!-- Visualization RVIZ -->
  <node if="$(arg rviz)" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d $(arg rviz_cfg)"/>
  <node if="$(arg rviz)" pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="points_xyzrgb" args="standalone rtabmap_ros/point_cloud_xyzrgb">
    <remap from="left/image"        to="$(arg left_image_topic_relay)"/>
    <remap from="right/image"       to="$(arg right_image_topic_relay)"/>
    <remap from="left/camera_info"  to="$(arg left_camera_info_topic)"/>
    <remap from="right/camera_info" to="$(arg right_camera_info_topic)"/>
    <remap from="rgb/image"         to="$(arg rgb_topic_relay)"/>
    <remap from="depth/image"       to="$(arg depth_topic_relay)"/>
    <remap from="rgb/camera_info"   to="$(arg camera_info_topic)"/>
    <remap from="cloud"             to="voxel_cloud" />

    <param name="decimation"  type="double" value="2"/>
    <param name="voxel_size"  type="double" value="0.02"/>
    <param name="approx_sync" type="bool"   value="$(arg approx_sync)"/>
  </node>

</launch>
```

How do I turn off transforms for 1)/map to /odom and 2)/odom to /camera_link?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292835/how-can-i-stop-rtabmap-from-publishing-transform-data-on-/tf-topic?/) by [Jetson_student_group](https://answers.ros.org/users/34099/jetson_student_group/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2018-05-31

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

if you are using only visual odometry, I suggest to use the node directly than using rtabmap.launch:

```
<node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rgbd_odometry" name="rgbd_odometry" output="screen">
  <remap from="rgb/image"       to="/camera/rgb/image_rect_color"/>
  <remap from="depth/image"     to="/camera/depth_registered/image_raw"/>
  <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="/camera/rgb/camera_info"/>
  <param name="frame_id"    type="string" value="camera_link"/>
  <param name="publish_tf"  type="bool"   value="false"/>
</node>
```

With `publish_tf` set to false, TF will not be published.

cheers,
Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2018-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jetson_student_group](https://answers.ros.org/users/34099/jetson_student_group/) on 2018-06-01**:
Hello Mathieu
Thanks a lot, This is just what I needed!
Can i ask some questions out of curiosity? Like 1]what does rtabmap use to generate visual odometry? 2]How can i increase the sampling rate of the code. should I create a new question for it?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2018-06-07**:\

1. By default, it uses OpenCV's feature matching and PnP estimation, with local bundle adjustment using g2o to refine motion (when built with g2o support). 2) visual odometry works as fast as it can. If odom frame rate is lower than camera frame rate, you have computation power limitation.